# Evaluate $\int_c (z - z^2) dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

In an exercise, it's given that $C$ is a circle such that $|z-2|=3$

Now I know that, a circle with radius $r$ can be represented by $z=re^{i\theta}$, hence,
$$
z-2=3e^{i\theta}  
\implies z=2+3e^{i\theta}  \implies dz=3ie^{i\theta}d\theta
$$
Also
$$z^2=(2+3e^{i\theta})^2 \implies z^2=4+9e^{2i\theta}+12e^{i\theta}$$

Now $ f(z)=z-z^2=-(2+9e^{i\theta}+9e^{2i\theta})$

So,
$$
\int_c(z-z^2)dz=\int_0^{2π}-(2+9e^{i\theta}+9e^{2i\theta})3ie^{i\theta}d\theta
\tag{1}
$$
We can write
$e^{i\theta}=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$

On solving (1) I am getting 0 whereas the answer given is 30

Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: The correct answer is $0$.

Answer (score 3):

By [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem), integral of an analytic function over any closed contour is zero.